# Google Play Games Service (GPGS) Realtime Multiplayer (RTMP) never matches on Android (iOS works)

Tags: android, c++, ios, android-ndk, google-play-games

We are trying to implement GPGS RTMP C++ and running into a strange issue.  We are following the default example used in ButtonClicker and actually have it working just fine between iOS devices.  However when we try the same code using two Android devices quick match never fully completes.

Using the Android build we can create a room but once the quick game matching starts to take place both devices get a room status change callback with the status of CONNECTING.  They remain stuck that way and we receive no other notifications past that point in any callbacks.  Again the same code is working when run on iOS and we assume everything has been set up correctly in the developer console since we have access to Google play and are able to achieve a successful room creation on both devices.

Also if I try to connect an Android to an iOS device I get the same behavior on the Android side, but the iOS device quickly shows the Android player's status change to disconnected in the OnConnectedSetChanged callback.

I have also rebuilt/reimported the android SDK projects (made sure we had latest SDK), made sure we are using 1.3 of the c++ project. Also using NDK 9d and Cocos2d-x v2.2.6

Just in case the following is a clue/red alert to someone who has got the answer. The other odd issue we are having with GPGS is achievements (in total or progress) they won't post/retain progress (no errors), but leaderboards do retain and progress... Maybe this is related.

We have also tried builds via alpha and beta distributions via google play (signed and zip aligned)

**EDIT: Adding more information**
Here is our logs from an Android to Android match:

```
02-19 18:24:44.252: D/cocos2d-x debug info(27707): jni:isConnected is defined.
02-19 18:24:44.262: D/DA2(27707): isConnected() called.
02-19 18:24:44.272: D/cocos2d-x debug info(27707): isConnected(true) JNI Done.
02-19 18:24:44.272: I/DA2_GPGStateManager(27707): Entering GPGSStateManager::IsAuthorized()
02-19 18:24:44.272: D/cocos2d-x debug info(27707): Checking if user is GPGS authorized: YES
02-19 18:24:46.492: D/cocos2d-x debug info(27707): created a room 1
02-19 18:24:46.492: D/cocos2d-x debug info(27707): MY PLAYER ID IS: p_CP2QiKTYldGO5wEQAQ : Player Y
02-19 18:24:46.812: D/cocos2d-x debug info(27707): OnRoomStatusChanged
02-19 18:24:46.812: D/cocos2d-x debug info(27707): GPG Room status changed to CONNECTING.
02-19 18:24:49.542: D/dalvikvm(27707): threadid=34: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
02-19 18:24:49.542: V/GamesNativeSDK(27707): Detaching from JVM on thread main_dispatch
```

**EDIT: Adding more information**
Here is our logs from an Android to iOS match from the iOS log perspective:

```
Cocos2d: OnRoomStatusChanged
Cocos2d: GPG Room status changed to CONNECTING.
2015-02-19 01:41:08.790 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: OP: 1
2015-02-19 01:41:08.791 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: CALL_STATE_CHANGED_OP: New state: 1
2015-02-19 01:41:08.792 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR: peer_capabilities must not be null in PeerStateMachine::WaitingForConnectionData
2015-02-19 01:41:08.793 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: WaitingForOutgoingRemoteConnectionNoSessionId-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2 transitionTo WaitingForConnectionData-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2
2015-02-19 01:41:09.070 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: OP: 6
2015-02-19 01:41:09.071 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: CALL_STATE_CHANGED_OP: New state: 6
2015-02-19 01:41:09.072 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: Not handled -- invoking default handler for:7002
2015-02-19 01:41:09.072 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR:  - unhandledMessage: message.type=7002
2015-02-19 01:41:09.073 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: OP: 14
2015-02-19 01:41:09.074 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: CALL_STATE_CHANGED_OP: New state: 14
2015-02-19 01:41:09.075 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: Not handled -- invoking default handler for:7002
2015-02-19 01:41:09.077 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR:  - unhandledMessage: message.type=7002
2015-02-19 01:41:09.194 dam[20540:2466969] INFO: Connection status: CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED reporting ? 0
2015-02-19 01:41:09.195 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: WaitingForConnectionData-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2 transitionTo ConnectedState-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2
Cocos2d: OnRoomStatusChanged
Cocos2d: GPG Room status changed to ACTIVE.
Cocos2d: PLAYER: Player X STATUS:2 IN ROOM: Y
Cocos2d: PLAYER: Player 6459 STATUS:2 IN ROOM: Y ID:p_CIuY5fK73c-kKRAB
2015-02-19 01:41:18.936 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: OP: 13
2015-02-19 01:41:18.937 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: CALL_STATE_CHANGED_OP: New state: 13
2015-02-19 01:41:18.938 dam[20540:2466969] INFO: Attempting to reconnect to: p_CIuY5fK73c-kKRAB
2015-02-19 01:41:18.938 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: ConnectedState-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2 transitionTo EntryState-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2
2015-02-19 01:41:18.940 dam[20540:2466969] INFO: Attempting to reconnect to: p_CIuY5fK73c-kKRAB
2015-02-19 01:41:18.941 dam[20540:2466969] INFO: Waiting for connection from p_CIuY5fK73c-kKRAB
2015-02-19 01:41:18.943 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: Setting peer 1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2 capabilities to 0
2015-02-19 01:41:18.944 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR: peer_capabilities must not be null in PeerStateMachine::WaitingForOutgoingRemoteConnectionNoSessionId
2015-02-19 01:41:18.945 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: EntryState-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2 transitionTo WaitingForOutgoingRemoteConnectionNoSessionId-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2
2015-02-19 01:41:18.946 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR: No session mapped for 1211971051
2015-02-19 01:41:18.947 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR:  - unhandledMessage: message.type=7008
2015-02-19 01:41:18.948 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: OP: 1
2015-02-19 01:41:18.949 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: CALL_STATE_CHANGED_OP: New state: 1
2015-02-19 01:41:18.951 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR: peer_capabilities must not be null in PeerStateMachine::WaitingForConnectionData
2015-02-19 01:41:18.953 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: WaitingForOutgoingRemoteConnectionNoSessionId-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2 transitionTo WaitingForConnectionData-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2
2015-02-19 01:41:19.262 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: Not handled -- invoking default handler for:6010
Cocos2d: OnConnectedSetChanged
Cocos2d: PLAYER: Player X STATUS:2 IN ROOM: N
Cocos2d: PLAYER: Player 6459 STATUS:4 IN ROOM: N
Cocos2d: GPGSRealtimeMultiplayerManager::disconnect() called.
Cocos2d: REMOVE PLAYER: Player X ID:p_CIedtPyuzNqXkwEQAQ
Cocos2d: GPGSRealtimeMultiplayerManager::disconnect() called.
2015-02-19 01:41:19.262 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR:  - unhandledMessage: message.type=6010
Cocos2d: REMOVE PLAYER: Player 6459 ID:p_CIuY5fK73c-kKRAB
Cocos2d: GPGSRealtimeMultiplayerManager::disconnect() called.
2015-02-19 01:41:19.268 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: Not handled -- invoking default handler for:6004
2015-02-19 01:41:19.269 dam[20540:2466969] INFO: Disconnecting all peers
2015-02-19 01:41:19.270 dam[20540:2466969] ERROR: Transitioning to LeavingRoomState with invalid player id!
Cocos2d: GPG Multiplayer room left unsuccessfully! (now what?)
Cocos2d: GPG Multiplayer room left unsuccessfully! (now what?)
2015-02-19 01:41:19.337 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: WaitingForConnectionData-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2 transitionTo EntryState-1j89l5beklypm389fttwl6uuy0@public.talk.google.com/games_andrB648F1B2
2015-02-19 01:41:19.339 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: OP: 12
2015-02-19 01:41:19.340 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: CALL_STATE_CHANGED_OP: New state: 12
2015-02-19 01:41:19.341 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR: No session mapped for 3259690520
2015-02-19 01:41:19.341 dam[20540:2466970] ERROR:  - unhandledMessage: message.type=7008
Cocos2d: LOBBY ROW DEALLOC
2015-02-19 01:41:19.556 dam[20540:2467034] VERBOSE: Request had Apiary Status Code: 0
Cocos2d: GPG Multiplayer room left successfully (Quick Game/Invite)
2015-02-19 01:41:19.585 dam[20540:2466970] INFO: PeerStateMachine: Not handled -- invoking default handler for:6010
2015-02-19 01:41:29.271 dam[20540:2466415] ERROR:  - unhandledMessage: message.type=48
2015-02-19 01:41:29.587 dam[20540:2466415] ERROR:  - unhandledMessage: message.type=48
```

I will post Android perspective logs as soon as I collect some. We are using the zip aligned and all the log prints are stripped.

Comment: Down voting is fine, but help us out here. What is this question missing? This is not a trivial problem. What is needed to make this a better question?

Comment: Both achievements and leaderboards have been working like a champ. The  achievement issue mentioned about  had an achievement id that had typo in them and was a completely unrelated. We still can't use the Google invite screens in cocos2d-x. As soon as the screens are shown the connected players are dropped. But we can use it for 1v1 hook ups.

Comment: You should open an issue on the gpg cpp samples github. Thanks for showing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

On Android the room state change was not announced like it was on iOS.
specifically the callback for:

```
IRealTimeEventListener::OnRoomStatusChanged
```

The solution was to examine *any* callback and check for a state change. To be completely sure we were keeping track of last known room state whenever a room participant change occurs.

In our case `OnParticipantStatusChanged` was the most critical.

Luckily it is a simple system and only a handful of callbacks with a room reference exist... O.o

We are able to play games between Android to Android and Android to iOS this way... Seems like a work around to track state this way, but maybe it will help someone! v1.2 and v1.3 both behaved this way.

I figured this out when I modified the [minimalist](https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples/tree/master/samples-android/minimalist) app (that runs in every version supported) to include operations from the [Button Clicker](https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples/tree/master/samples-android/ButtonClicker) sample app (which required later versions of Android to leverage JUI for the ui components.) It was a complete accident that I sent data and noticed it was received... I am glad I was paying attention.

Comment: Glad it helped out. This took us a while to figure out. Its a workaround anyway... we haven't tried to see if there is a new fix yet. It works *most* of the time...

Comment: The problem I was having was with SDKBOX and their implementation of GPS Realtime multiplayer, some callbacks were not trigger on Android devices. So after reading this I tested each callback between Android - Android and Android - iOS and found only `P2PDisconnected()` wasn't working. So now I'll monitor all callbacks for room changes and specifically `OnParticipantStatusChanged ` for participant info.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped. What version of the sdk are you using?